# Suggest Spring batch solution

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

In our application, we have around 1000 customers and need to process some data on fortnightly basis. Data processing logic for each customer involves, around 4 rest calls to different service. We need to do this in spring batch to achieve performance.

Steps to process data --

1. Read all customers
2. For each customer process data by making 4 rest calls to different microservices
3. Write result to DB tables

As per my understanding, we should use, spring remote partitioner. Please suggest

Comment: Why a remote partitioner?  How much parallelism can the REST calls handle?  You can easily overload those services with batch with the wrong architecture...

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually i was thinking about this https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning   What could be best approach where i have to make rest calls to microservice for each customer

Comment: I understand that but my question still stands as far as how many REST API calls you can make at a time without overloading the server.

Comment: Oh yeah. Microservices which we will be calling for each customer from each step are highly available. So they should serve the purpose without overloading. Dont know the exact count at this moment.  Thanks for response

Comment: Then you can start with something as simple as the multithreaded step or partitioning within your JVM with threads.  Have you done any profiling to determine that you need the extra JVMs to make all the calls?

Comment: Thanks. Yes we thought about extra jvm. Can you point out any sample app or code on this. Thanks

Comment: Check out this talk and associated Github repository: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6IPlfm7N6w